# Two different SwitchCompats in two different activities

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I have 2 different SwithCompat in 2 different activity, what i want to achieve is, if i click the SwitchCompat in Activity A, the SwitchCompat in Acitivity B will be clicked as well. Vice Versa.

Can i achieve this with this code :

```
aSwitch = findViewById(R.id.switchs);
        aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
              //do something
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: get switch1 value and store it in a static variable and set to switch2

Comment: First, you will have to save the current switch state in some place (eg: static values or shared preferences). Then when you go to an Activity on create, check the saved value and update the switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all when you are pass bundle for open second activity pass with bundle

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.putString(key, value);
mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
```

and get bundle in second activity

```
boolean value = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean(key);
```

according to boolean value you can change switch on and off

Comment: Can i get the bundle value even when i'm not open the second activity ?

Comment: not from bundle but you have already value of SwitchCompect true or false.on same activity

Answer (score 0):

You can define interface as a callback in activity one use to activity two like this :

```
    public class ActivityOne{ 

           private ICallback mICallback;
           private SwitchCompat mSwitchButton;

            public interface ICallback {

                void getData(boolean state);

            }

mSwitchButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {

            mICallback.getData(isChecked);
        }
    });
    }
```

And in TwoActivity:

```
public class TwoActivity implements OneActivity.ICallback{

  @Override
    public void getData(boolean state) {

//YOU CAN USE IT HERE IN SECOND ACTIVITY

    }

}
```

Maybe you face to callback is null in first activity then you should pass context when you going to second activity from first activity.